# Get least used id within another table

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have two tables

Account table

```
id INT, username TEXT, password TEXT, proxy_id INT, enabled BOOLEAN
```

Proxy table

```
id INT, proxy_ip TEXT, proxy_port INT
```

I would have a loop that goes through accounts one at a time. I want the least used proxy to be assigned to table.proxy_id.

for example if we have 2 proxies in the proxy table and 5 accounts in the Account table

```
1 10.0.0.1  4000
2 10.0.0.1  4001
```

Our accounts

```
1 david    password 2    enabled
2 mark     password 1    enabled
3 jessica  password 1    enabled
4 ashley   password NULL enabled
5 allan    password NULL enabled
6 james    password 2    disabled
```

My program will loop in Java that goes through all the enabled accounts, it will assign the least used proxy in the enabled accounts to the account. In the example above David, mark and Jessica already have a proxy set. So the loop will go through Ashley and proxy with id 2 needs to be assigned to Ashley as it is the least used. For Allan proxy 1 or 2 can be assigned since it would be the least used in any case. James should be ignored since his account is not enabled.

I hope I was clear in my question. I think this would need to be done in two queries?

Comment: And how big is the proxy table really?  And how big is the account table?

Comment: The proxy table can be around 1000 rows. The accounts tables can be around max 50k

Comment: You can find the minimum count of proxy ids from accounts table and then assign those to the ones having null and enables.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ --- If you think you need two queries, try writing them and see it that works. I don't see how you could do it in less, since you need to read all enabled account records, but also need to find any unused proxy record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Java with SQL for this. But it makes it easier to read. I have tested it and it works

```
  public void setLeastUsedProxy() throws Exception {
    Database db = new Database();

    ArrayList<Integer> allProxies = db.getAllProxies();
    ArrayList<Integer> allAssignedProxies = db.getAssignedProxies();

    ArrayList<Integer> unusedProxies = allProxies;
    unusedProxies.removeAll(allAssignedProxies);

    // assign the unused proxy
    if (unusedProxies.size() > 0) {

    } else {
      Integer leastUsedProxy = db.getLeastUsedProxy();
      System.out.println(leastUsedProxy);
    }

  }
```

And below are your SQL methods

```
  public ArrayList<Integer> getAssignedProxies() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    try {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
      pst = conn
          .prepareStatement("select distinct(proxy_id) from account where proxy_id IS NOT null AND enabled = true");

      rs = pst.executeQuery();

      while (rs.next()) {
        list.add(rs.getInt("proxy_id"));
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (pst != null) {
        pst.close();
      }
      if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
      }
      if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
      }
    }

    return list;
  }

  public ArrayList<Integer> getAllProxies() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    try {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
      pst = conn.prepareStatement("select distinct(id) from proxy");

      rs = pst.executeQuery();

      while (rs.next()) {
        list.add(rs.getInt("id"));
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (pst != null) {
        pst.close();
      }
      if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
      }
      if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
      }
    }

    return list;
  }

  public Integer getLeastUsedProxy() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    Integer leastUsedProxy = null;

    try {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
      pst = conn
          .prepareStatement("SELECT proxy_id, count(proxy_id) FROM account GROUP by proxy_id ORDER BY count LIMIT 1");

      rs = pst.executeQuery();

      while (rs.next()) {
        leastUsedProxy = rs.getInt("proxy_id");
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (pst != null) {
        pst.close();
      }
      if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
      }
      if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
      }
    }

    return leastUsedProxy;
  }
```

Comment: This approach is expensive.  If performance is an issue, you want to see if you can use set operations for the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea.  You need to expand the proxy ids to get the list that you need for assignment.  The following is a rudimentary way of doing this, but it is not that hard.  Assign an extra 100 "rows" to each id and start enumerating them from the current count.  Then order these for the assignment.

For the first part:

```
select p.id, count(a.id) as cnt,
       generate_series(1, 100) + count(a.id) as proxy_seqnum
from proxy p left join
     accounts a
     on p.id = a.proxy_id and a.enabled 
group by p.id;
```

Now, calculate an overall sequential ordering:

```
select ap.*, row_number() over (order by proxy_seqnum) as seqnum
from (select p.id, count(a.id) as cnt,
             generate_series(1, 100) + count(a.id) as proxy_seqnum
      from proxy p left join
           accounts a
           on p.id = a.proxy_id and a.enabled 
      group by p.id
     ) ap;
```

We can use this sequential ordering to match back to a sequential ordering of the accounts.  This will give the the proxy ids in order of their "rarity", resulting in a more balanced final result.

To do this we need to calculate the seqnum for the accounts:

```
update accounts a
    set proxy_id = p.id;
    from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
          from accounts
         ) aa join
         (select ap.*, row_number() over (order by proxy_seqnum) as seqnum
          from (select p.id, count(a.id) as cnt,
                       generate_series(1, 100) + count(a.id) as proxy_seqnum
                from proxy p left join
                     accounts a
                     on p.id = a.proxy_id and a.enabled 
                group by p.id
               ) ap
           ) p
           on a.seqnum = p.seqnum
    where a.enabled and a.proxy_id is null and
          aa.id = a.id;
```